# Uncaught TypeError: snap.data() is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

when i sign-up it displays the following error on the browser but the user gets added in the firebase and on refreshing the browser there is no error.

[error on clicking signup button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QTeh.png)

this is my code snippet.

```
fb.firestore
            .collection('chatUsers')
            .doc(authUser.uid)
            .onSnapshot(snap => {
              setChatConfig({
                userSecret: authUser.uid,
                avatar: snap.data().avatar,
                userName: snap.data().userName,
                projectID: '###################',
              });
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say without seeing the database. [According to the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data), `.data()` returns `undefined` if the specified document from the `.doc()` call does not exists.

So, because `snap.data()` is returning `undefined`, it seems the document at the location `authUser.uid` doesn't exist in the collection `chatUsers`.

Perhaps check upstream in your chain at some of the values. Maybe `authUser.uid` is initially `null` until the user data is fetched form the database? This is a guess without knowing more about your project.

Another idea is to handle the possibility of a document not existing within your `onSnapshot()` callback function. So for example:

```
fb.firestore
            .collection('chatUsers')
            .doc(authUser.uid)
            .onSnapshot(snap => {
              if (snap.data() === "undefined") {
                console.log("no user")
              } else { 
                setChatConfig({
                  userSecret: authUser.uid,
                  avatar: snap.data().avatar,
                  userName: snap.data().userName,
                  projectID: '###################',
                });
              }
            })
```

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: OP's problem sounds like a race condition. They seem to create a user, then save their user data (maybe with a Cloud Function) but attach the listener before their user data has been committed to the database

Comment: This makes sense. Wouldn't using a condition in `.onSnapshot()` that checks against `snap.data()` being `undefined` like I have in the example above fix this? If a listener is attached at the documents location, once the CF finishes the write to that location the listener would fire again, this time having the user data. This scenario would be better solved using an async solution, but sticking strictly with the code provided above wouldn't my example work?

Comment: I didn't say your solution wouldn't work, just that your dealing with a symptom rather than the root cause of the problem. Anyways, `snap.data() === "undefined"` needs to be `typeof snap.data() === "undefined"` for it to actually work - but you are better off using [`snap.exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#exists) instead. You also want to avoid calling `snap.data()` multiple times if you can - either use it once like in `const docData = snap.data()` or use the getters like in `snap.get("avatar")`.

Comment: Solid. Thanks for the input.